# Return specific property when accessing a Struct without referencing its name

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is there a way in Swift that I can get a property from a struct without having to reference it?

For example

```
public struct ASValue<T: Hashable>: Hashable {
    private let id = UUID()
    public var item: T
    
    public init(item: T) {
        self.item = item
    }
}

let val = ASValue(item: "Example")

print(val) // Prints: Example
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean, exactly?

Comment: @Alexander If I call `val` it should return the property I want it to by default. So for example here I would want it to just return `item` without having to call `val.item`

Comment: Are you thinking of a property wrapper? Could you elaborate on what exactly you're trying to do? I.e., if this existed, what would you use it for?

Comment: @Alexander The item is passed as a generic and converted to `ASValue` for internal use. I’m using this to build a package but want to avoid having to use `.item` when referencing that ASValue since all it has is a private id and then the actual item.

Comment: What's the "internal use" mean, exactly? That seems like the interesting part

Answer (score 5):

It's possible by adopting `CustomStringConvertible` and constraining `T` also to `CustomStringConvertible`

```
public struct ASValue<T: Hashable>: Hashable, CustomStringConvertible where T: CustomStringConvertible {
    
    private let id = UUID()
    public var item: T
    
    public var description : String {
        return "\(item)"
    }
}

let val = ASValue(item: "Example")

print(val) // Prints: Example
```

And this is a struct, the `init` method is for free.

Comment: This will always be returned as a strong thought right? I would like if I could get it as a generic type so if it’s an int I could use it.

Comment: The argument of `print` is required to be `String`. There is no built-in way to return `item` as a generic type.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But what I want is where it returns the generic property as whatever type is is that way I can use it in calculations as well

Comment: I’m trying to specifically avoid that as this is for a package I’m building. The item is passed as a generic and converted to `ASValue` for internal use. I thought about making a second property with just a type of `T` but then that wouldn’t solve the issue of still needing `.item`. I just want to always pass out the item without needing to directly reference it.

Comment: Not possible in Swift. `val` has the type it has. You could maybe look at downcasting, but that syntax will not be an improvement.

Comment: You might look into property wrappers: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/property-wrappers-in-swift/

Comment: @JoeScotto Man, this is almost certainly an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Rather than telling us what your actual problem is (that you're trying to solve with this design of "ASValue"), you're asking us about some minutia on the solution you *think* might be best. Just tell us the original problem. Most likely there's a better solution that entirely side-steps the question in your post.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is exactly provided with [property wrappers in swift](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html#ID348). You have to make your `ASValue` structproperty wrapper by applying `@propertyWrapper` to the declaration:

```swift
@propertyWrapper
public struct ASValue<T: Hashable>: Hashable {
    private let id = UUID()
    public var wrappedValue: T

    public init(wrappedValue: T) {
        self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
    }
}
```

Then you can use this wrapper to wrap any property in another type and access that property directly. You can even access the `ASValue` wrapper type by prefixing with `_`:

```swift
class SomeClass {
    @ASValue var val = "Example"

    func printVal() {
        // print(_val) for actual value
        print(val) // Prints: Example
    }
}
```

You can also pass this property with its wrapper identity to other function:

```swift
func printVal<T: Hashable>(@ASValue val: T) {
    // print(_val) for actual value
    print(val) // Prints: Example
}

let obj = SomeClass()
printVal(val: obj.val)
```

If for some constraint you can't use the property wrapper approach you can try the `@dynamicCallable` attribute as a workaround. This allows values created from your types to be invoked as methods with specified arguments.

```swift
@dynamicCallable
public struct ASValue<T: Hashable>: Hashable {
    private let id = UUID()
    public var item: T

    public init(item: T) {
        self.item = item
    }

    // need to have withArguments with argument type confirming
    // to ExpressibleByArrayLiteral
    func dynamicallyCall(withArguments arg: [Int] = []) -> T {
        return item
    }
}

let val = ASValue(item: "Example")
print(val()) // Prints: Example
```